# why can't I load another page into an iframe the following way?

Tags: html

I want to have an Iframe, so that when I click on a button, another page loads into it.

```
<html>
<body>

<form method=get action=http://www.google.com accept-charset="UTF-8" target="my_form">

<input type=submit>
</form>

<iframe name="my_form" id="my_form" width=80%> </iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't work on Firefox or Chrome. Does it work for anyone?

Comment: Don't be sloppy with the quotes around your attributes. Always use them.

Comment: I fixed the grammar in your title, but you should change it to something more descriptive if you actually want folks to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work because it violates the "same origin policy".

Try running this in Chrome, and check your console.

This is what you should see:

> Refused to display
>   'https://www.google.is/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=lMffVJSdJ5LfaseMguAD' in a
>   frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

More info here: http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy

Comment: interesting. I think this is something new -- this page used to work just fine until a month or so ago.